# Check the server for new updates using Jsoup every hour

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifications, push-notification, jsoup

I'm working on university application and I'm using Jsoup Library [Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/) to get the news article from the university website , but I want to check every hour if there any new article added to push notification to the user

and my approach is to save the title of latest article in shared preferences and make my app every hour in background to get the last article  and compare it with  the last one and push notification if they are different

**My Question** : How to make my app do that in the background every hour?

**another thing** is that a good approach? because doing that every hour will drain the battery user, is there another way to check for news better than this? 
by the way: I don't have any permission on the university website to use GCM or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use AlarmManager

its OK to do like that, i have some apps do something like that too

here some tutorial
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Alarm Manager:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Long Answer:
No a repeating alarm isn't a great solution but I see you have no control over your university server which rules out GCM :( Read the section in the link above on **Understand the Trade-offs** this is interesting. You may want to consider a sync adapter as this will also help improve your shared preferences solution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested use AlarmManager.

In addition, you can also use HTTP If-Modified-Since: date or an HTTP Etag to check if the file was modified.

Also, another approach would be to allow users to  set their required update rate, allowing them to define their own balance between data freshness and battery life.
For more information check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html)